# Tweepy error code 400

Tags: python, anaconda, tweepy

I am trying to download some tweets for research purpose the code worked very well until a few days ago.

Error Message

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "<ipython-input-1-10547a7aea4c>", line 1, in <module>
>     runfile('F:/twitter_locations_n_scraper/02_twitterscrapping.py', wdir='F:/twitter_locations_n_scraper')
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
> line 668, in runfile
>     execfile(filename, namespace)
> 
>   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
> line 108, in execfile
>     exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
> 
>   File "F:/twitter_locations_n_scraper/02_twitterscrapping.py", line
> 70, in <module>
>     for item in cursor.items(1000): # Remove the limit to 1000
> 
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py",
> line 49, in __next__
>     return self.next()
> 
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py",
> line 197, in next
>     self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
> 
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py",
> line 108, in next
>     data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kargs)
> 
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py",
> line 250, in _call
>     return method.execute()
> 
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py",
> line 234, in execute
>     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
> 
> TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400
```

I did try the supposed solution

```
api.update_status('Test')
```

But this does not work for me, I did change the keys and still I am facing the same error, Reinstalled the Tweepy Package twice and yet the error does not go.

Appreciate the help in solving the error, Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Code that I am getting error

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import sys
import time

path="F:\\twitter_locations_n_scraper\\"


ckey = '*****'
csecret = '******'
atoken = '*****'
asecret = '*****'

def toDataFrame(tweets):
    # COnvert to data frame
    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()

    DataSet['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetText'] = [tweet.text.encode('utf-8') for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetRetweetCt'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetFavoriteCt'] = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetSource'] = [tweet.source for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetCreated'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userID'] = [tweet.user.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userScreen'] = [tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userName'] = [tweet.user.name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userCreateDt'] = [tweet.user.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userDesc'] = [tweet.user.description for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFollowerCt'] = [tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFriendsCt'] = [tweet.user.friends_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userLocation'] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userTimezone'] = [tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Coordinates'] = [tweet.coordinates for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['GeoEnabled'] = [tweet.user.geo_enabled for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Language'] = [tweet.user.lang for tweet in tweets]
    tweets_place= []
    #users_retweeted = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.place:
            tweets_place.append(tweet.place.full_name)
        else:
            tweets_place.append('null')
    DataSet['TweetPlace'] = [i for i in tweets_place]
    #DataSet['UserWhoRetweeted'] = [i for i in users_retweeted]

    return DataSet

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret,'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
#auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler('******', '*******')

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    df=pd.read_csv(path+"00_all_location_India_full.csv")

    print ("Scraping data now") # Enter lat and long and radius in Kms
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        x="%s,%s,30km"%(df['latitude'][i],df['longitude'][i]) #,q='motox4', since='2018-08-16',until='2018-08-18',
        cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,since='2018-08-23',until='2018-08-24',lang='en',count=1000)
        results=[]
        print (i)
        for item in cursor.items(1000): # Remove the limit to 1000
            results.append(item)
        DataSet = toDataFrame(results)
        DataSet['latitude']=df['latitude'][i]
        DataSet['longitude']=df['longitude'][i]
        DataSet['radius']=30
        del DataSet['Coordinates']
        DataSet.to_csv(path+'cities_aug23.csv',encoding='utf-8',index=False,mode="a")
```

Comment: What code do you execute?

Comment: @jalazbe Included code

Answer (score 2):

according to twitter official api page . 
the code 400 indicates the following error's , 
so your issue is caused by one of those listed below reasons please check them one by one :

-attachment_url parameter is invalid    Corresponds with HTTP 400. The URL value provided is not a URL that can be attached to this Tweet.

-Bad authentication data    Corresponds with HTTP 400. The method requires authentication but it was not presented or was wholly invalid.

-parameter is invalid   Corresponds with HTTP 400. The URL value provided is not a URL
 that can be attached to this Tweet.

-Bad Request    The request was invalid or cannot be otherwise served. An accompanying error message will explain further. 
Requests without authentication are considered invalid and will yield this response.

-Animated GIFs are not allowed when uploading multiple images.  Corresponds with HTTP 400. Only one animated GIF may be attached to a single tweet

-The validation of media ids failed.    Corresponds with HTTP 400. There was a problem with the media ID submitted with the Tweet.

-A media id was not found.  Corresponds with HTTP 400. The media ID attached to the Tweet was not found.

-The given URL is invalid.  Corresponds with HTTP 400. A URL included in the Tweet could not be handled. This may be because a non-ASCII URL could not be converted, or for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting question  , actually , the way you wrote your question have lead me to write this answer ,

you have mention that it was working but not any more , so this could happen in my opinion for 2 reason ...

browser have depreciated some function within the browser which prevents the script to work . maybe you should try to preventDefault() function on page load and see if any error appears. 
try also changing your internet connection , or restart your modem
Also make sure your loading this from https website not http .

or these path's which you listed on your code , probably there is no permission access to read it , i have big doubts about this path , however you check all path's and try to close anything that might block connections to these path's .

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\

because it require windows authentication to access it . try minimize your UAC permission from control panel . you may also check the security tab by right clicking on the folder and selecting properties .

so , revert everything back as it is and check the above .
please let me know the result as i can edit it accordingly to the results of your replay

hope my post helps you .

Comment: I did try the options, but don't see any difference.. And about the path its the input and output file path.. There is no browser as such that I am using for http/https any other solutions?

Comment: alright i got u .. i will dig into this and let u know

Comment: What is python version u r using ?

Comment: Updated python 3.x with anaconda on windows 10 , 64 bit environment

Comment: check new answer , maybe gif animated pic is causing that ? cus according to twitter api page it cannot be out of these reasons

Answer (score 0):

Twitter recently made big changes to its API, removing a large amount of features used by Twitter clients and scrapers. As HTTP 400 is 'Bad Request', and your code was working up until recently (when the change was made) I would say it's fairly safe to assume this is the cause. See [details](https://twitter.com/TwitterAPI/status/1030122500561166336).

Comment: What could be the solution ? or an alternative for downloading the public tweets ?

Comment: Actually, [it seems that's not the issue](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1095).

Comment: Additionally, it says [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/details-and-what-to-expect-from-the-api-deprecations-this-week-on-august-16-2018/110746) that twitter will return 410 and 404, not plain 400s. Though the API changes seem to be the most reasonable cause of this issue.

Comment: As mentioned here, the user and site streaming API's are deprecated and replaced by `Account Activity API` which you can get by a premium or an enterprise subscription.

Comment: @SoumithriChilakamarri so you mean to say we cannot get stream tweets here after ?

Comment: @SitzBlogz Check out this thread in the comment section: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179345/tweepy-tweepy-error-tweeperror-code-215-message-bad-authentication-data/52191535#52191535... If you are reading keys from a file, make sure that your keys are passed as a string

Comment: @SoumithriChilakamarri I am reading latitude, longitude and the name of the location which is not key its plain text

Comment: @SitzBlogz I was referring to your `twitter API keys` not the keys in your `dictionary`

Comment: @SoumithriChilakamarri Yes the keys are in directly given in the program and all of them as enclosed with single quote